# Template class that accepts any STL container and creates a vector of pointers to its elements (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, vector, containers

I want to create a template class that accepts any standard library container (most importantly: vectors, and strings). This, so far is not a problem. However, I want to store a vector of pointers in this class and the pointers within this vector should each point to the individual elements of the accepted container.

My impression is that this would allow me to change the values in the original container (as long as their type, and the container size doesn't change), without touching the template class entity. So I would have a vector of pointers always pointing to my original container elements regardless of their values or what the original container's container-type was.

How could I achieve this? When I pass a string to my template class, and try to print each value my pointers are pointing to, I get a strange result. Passing "Hello" and then trying to print it with a for-cycle results in:

ello
llo
lo
o

Seems to me like I'm not passing my original string char-by-char into the pointer vector.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems you have tried something. Can you show us your code attempt?

Comment: Sounds like you got it working! When printing using `std::cout`, a `char*` is interpreted as a pointer to a null-terminated string. So it will print the character that the pointer points to, plus any other character that comes after, until it encounters a null byte (you got lucky there -- `std::string` is not null-terminated). This is why you're getting all suffixes of the input string. You probably want to dereference the pointer so you can print the raw `char` instead.

Comment: @Thomas `std::string` is guaranteed to be null-terminated as of `c++11` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string))

Comment: Then OP got lucky that they're using a C++11 compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class Container>
auto
pointer_to_elements(Container&& container)
{
    using T = typename std::decay_t<Container>::value_type; // type of contained element
    std::vector<T*> ret;
    for (auto& element : container) {
        ret.push_back(std::addressof(element));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It would probably be necessary to reject rvalue references for the parameter to avoid dangling pointers.

It can be used as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello";
    auto ptrs = pointer_to_elements(s);
    for (auto& ptr : ptrs) {
        std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your approach will most often not work.

Memory in containers may be reallocated. Without the chance for you to notice that. Then your pointer would show to indeterminate memory.

While you can write a program that seems to work, it will nmost likely fail.

You should not do that . . .

Comment: Wouldn't that happen only if I resized that container? Suppose I declare a vector and start adding items. The computer allocates a certain amount of memory at a certain location in memory for this vector. If I keep adding items, then when that memory location is filled, it searches for a new, bigger location, moves the original vector, and then I can keep adding more items. But until this happens, the vector is supposed to stay where it is, isn't it? And by extension pointers pointing to it should keep working as intended, shouldn't they?

Comment: In my question, I stated that the container that's passed to the template class does not change in size, or in contained data type.